# ERROR: ifelse(d==0,NA,d), where d is integer64 return nonsense (in "num" form)

Tags: r

Aparently `ifelse` completelly changes the numbers and does not preserve the data type of the input

For example:

```
library(bit64)
d <- c(1:10,NA,12,0) %>% as.integer64()
d %>% str
Class 'integer64'  num [1:13] 4.94e-324 9.88e-324 1.48e-323 1.98e-323 2.47e-323 ...

ifelse(d==0,NA,d) %>% str
 num [1:13] 4.94e-324 9.88e-324 1.48e-323 1.98e-323 2.47e-323 ...
ifelse(d==0,5,d) %>% str
num [1:13] 4.94e-324 9.88e-324 1.48e-323 1.98e-323 2.47e-323 ...
ifelse(d==5,50,d) %>% str
num [1:13] 4.94e-324 9.88e-324 1.48e-323 1.98e-323 5.00e+01 ...
```

Above: 
- numbers in the output are nonsense
- the output of the format is "num"

Is this a know problem?

Is there another function to use instead of `ifelse`?

Edit1: replacing the `ifelse` with a data.table operation

```
d <- data.table(a=c(1:10,NA,12,0) %>% as.integer64 )
d[a==0,a:=NA]
d
                       a
 1:                   1
 2:                   2
 3:                   3
 4:                   4
 5:                   5
 6:                   6
 7:                   7
 8:                   8
 9:                   9
10:                  10
11:                  NA
12:                  12
13: 9218868437227407266

#obve: still incorrect, NA was interpreted as a nonsense integer64

#now this works:
    d <- data.table(a=c(1:10,NA,12,0) %>% as.integer64 )
d[a==0,a:=as.integer64(NA)]
d
     a
 1:  1
 2:  2
 3:  3
 4:  4
 5:  5
 6:  6
 7:  7
 8:  8
 9:  9
10: 10
11: NA
12: 12
13: NA
```

Edit2: tryed pading the outputs of ifelse as.integer64(). Does not work!

```
d <- c(1:10,NA,12,0) %>% as.integer64()
ifelse(d==0,as.integer64(NA),as.integer64(d))
 [1] 4.940656e-324 9.881313e-324 1.482197e-323 1.976263e-323 2.470328e-323 2.964394e-323 3.458460e-323 3.952525e-323
 [9] 4.446591e-323 4.940656e-323            NA 5.928788e-323  0.000000e+00
```

Edit 3: added source package (bit64)

Comment: which package are you using for `integer64` (bit64?)?

Comment: A quite good summary of the deficiencies of `ifelse` was summarized here together with a discussion of a new `ifelse2` version: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2016-August/072970.html

Comment: @RYoda: yes I am using the bit64 package (just updated the question with this

Answer (score 5):

The data type `integer64` from the `bit64` package internally uses the only 64 bit data type that is available in R: `double`

This implies some limitations in the current implementation of the package, e. g.:

- `str`: inherited from Base R, does not print values correctly
- `NA` must be replaced with `NA_integer64_`

Please read the documentation for more details: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit64/bit64.pdf

To make your example work using `ifelse` you must

1. assign the `integer64` class to the result of `ifelse` again (since it is lost due to [known deficiencies](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2016-August/072970.html) with `ifelse`) and
2. use `NA_integer64_` instead of `NA`

like this:

```
library(bit64)
library(dplyr)
d <- c(1:10,NA_integer64_,12,0) %>% as.integer64()
d
# integer64
# [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 0  12 0 
class(d)
# [1] "integer64"
e <- ifelse(d==0,NA_integer64_,d)
e
# [1] 4.940656e-324 9.881313e-324 1.482197e-323 1.976263e-323 2.470328e-323 2.964394e-323 3.458460e-323 3.952525e-323 4.446591e-323
# [10] 4.940656e-323  0.000000e+00 5.928788e-323  0.000000e+00
class(e)
# [1] "numeric"
class(e) <- "integer64"
e
# integer64
# [1] 1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   <NA> 12   <NA>
```

If you were calling `str` now (which is **not** supported by `bit64`) you will see garbage again:

```
> str(e)        # same as:  e %>% str
Class 'integer64'  num [1:13] 4.94e-324 9.88e-324 1.48e-323 1.98e-323 2.47e-323 ...
```